# How can I use database result outside of scope in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am developing node js app. When I fetch result from server (using sequelize) results can be used only inside.

Below function not works. I want to change result due to type_id.

```
result = device.map(function(el) {
                        var o = Object.assign({}, el);
        o.TypeValue = 'ABC';  //if i have put here something it works, but below gives null
                        if (el.type_id == 1) {
                            Cpu.findById(el.type_id, { attributes: ['name'] })
                                .then(typevalue => {
                                    o.TypeValue = typevalue.name; //this works only inside this
                                });
                        }if(el.type_id==2){...}...

                            return o; //o is null
                    });
```

Comment: because it's a `promise` so `async` you have to either return the promise or use a callback. check the docs for more info [sequelize findById](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findById).

Comment: ugh, that indentation is almost random, no wonder you can't see the problem - but, `o is null` is not plausible unless some code you haven't shown specifically does `o = null;` - even if `el` is undefined or null, `o` must be at least `{TypeValue: 'ABC'}` when you return it

Comment: @vikscool How can I solve this problem. There have multiple if clauses.....

Comment: @Benfactor you can put the `if` conditions inside of your `then()` if only `Cpu.findById()` is going to be called else if there are different conditions then you need to create a base object outside of `map` and then just populate when the condition is processed.